# How detailed should my work experience be?

Tags: resume

I only have one year experience within the field I work (web development), but after finishing writing my CV, my work experience occupies almost an entire A4 page, detailing the projects I worked to, technologies used etc. Is that too much? Would that turn an employer away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked,

> How detailed should my work experience be?

The short answer is, **detailed enough to show that you have the right skills and experience to do the job, and no more detailed than that.** Resumes are sales tools - you're trying to sell yourself to an employer. Look at other forms of sales tools - they're not all the same, but rarely to you get hit with details that aren't relevant, given a specific situation.

In other words, there isn't a single correct answer - it will be circumstantial. In some cultures and for some jobs, a one page resume may be typical. In other cases, employers may expect two, three, or four pages - especially for a more senior position or other situation where there are requirements that are both broad and deep.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding.  CV's are rather verbose; outlining projects, experiences, certs, and degrees.  I would think a full comprehensive report of your experiences and successes that complete a single page would be perfectly acceptable for a person in the trenches for a year.